# Fixing an infinite loop in java

Tags: java, infinite

My program won't stop running, and I'm not sure what I've done wrong. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      ArrayList<NumberOperations> numOpsList = new ArrayList<NumberOperations>();

      System.out.println("Enter a list of positive integers separated "
                        + "with a space followed by 0:");


      int x = in.nextInt(); 

      NumberOperations newNumOp = null;

      while (x != 0) {
         newNumOp = new NumberOperations(x);

         numOpsList.add(newNumOp); 

         int index = 0;

         while (index < numOpsList.size()) {
            NumberOperations num = numOpsList.get(index);
            System.out.println("For: " + num);

            // add print statement for odds under num
            System.out.println("\tOdds Under: " + newNumOp.oddsUnder());

            // add print statement for powers of 2 under num
            System.out.println("\tPowers of 2 under: " + newNumOp.powersTwoUnder());

            index++;
         } 
      }

   }
```

Comment: You can start by modifying `x`.

Comment: explain what your program does and what is the expected result?

Comment: Why do you expect it to stop?

Comment: It takes in an int value and determines the odd numbers and powers of two that are less than the value entered. This is just the driver program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `x = in.nextInt();` has to be inside the while loop.

```
...

int x = -1; 
...

while (x != 0) {

     x = in.nextInt();
     ....
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be checking either index instead of x or using x--

X is never being set to zero which is causing your infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop condition `x` that you never change:

```
 While (x != 0){
  // loop code
 }
```

However, loop code doesn´t change the x value.